# StackView not stretching, hugging content

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

i got an issue with a UIStackView that won't stretch to the superviews bounds.
i've added constraints to the stackView to fill it's superview with a left and right margin. But instead of doing so it resizes it to it's content size. I've set the `distribution` to `.equalSpacing` and `axis` to `.horizontal`.

[image]

In a test project with just the stackView it works fine (despite the fact that in my actual project i'm doing it in code and in the test project in IB).
Here the constraints of the content views get correctly ignored and the stackView takes the space of the superview

[image]

i tried changing contentHugging for both contentViews and stackView but nothing changed. Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it myself, problem was that the stackView is inside a UIScrollView to make it scrollable once the stackView extends the screen bounds. As adding constraints to a subview of a scrollView does relate to the contentSize of the scrollView not the frame, the constraints could not be resolved correctly.

I ended up adding constraints to the superview in `didMoveToSuperview()`

Hopefully this may help someone :)